# Check if strings from a list in a text and return first longest match

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to design an application that binds a phrase or word to some item, for example image, and saves phrase-item pair in the database. Then it receives a text, and if it contains binded substring, corresponding item should be returned. 
It should return only one item (first match), and longest substrings should take precedence.

I wrote a function, that returns expected values:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get_item(text, bindings): 
    text = text.lower()
    matches = []
    for phrase, item in bindings:
        phrase = phrase.lower()
        index = text.find(phrase)
        if index != -1:
            matches.append((phrase, item, index))
    if matches:
        matches.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True)
        matches.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
        item_id = matches[0][1]
    else:
        item_id = None
    return item_id
```

Example:

```
bindings = [
('i', 'item1'), ('like', 'item2'), ('i like', 'item3'), ('turtles', 'item4'),
]
text = 'I like turtles!'
print(get_item(text, bindings)) # should return item3
```

Is there cleaner ways to complete such task, or faster, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an early return in your function to get rid of a few lines, because python's default return value is already `None`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get_item(text, bindings): 
    text = text.lower()
    matches = []
    for phrase, item in bindings:
        index = text.find(phrase)
        if index != -1:
            matches.append((phrase, item, index))
    if matches:
        matches.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True)
        matches.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
        return matches[0][1]
```

Algorithm wise, I'm not sure this code is up to the specification you wrote. You said, phrases should be preferred over single words. However, you only sort by length. Therefore

```
bindings = [('i am a', 'item1'), ('terminator', 'item2')]
text = 'I am a terminator'
print get_item(text, bindings)
```

will print `'item2'` and not `'item1'`, even though it is a single word and the other binding is a phrase. Maybe also use something like `len(x[0].split())` to give you the number of words as the sort key?

Also, your code scales with something like \$\mathcal{O}(m)*\mathcal{O}(n*k)\$, where \$m\$ is the number of defined bindings, \$n\$ is the length of the text and \$k\$ is the average length of the phrases in the bindings. I'm not sure whether there is a better algorithm, though.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Bindings are supposed to be in lowercase (I've added second lower() call to the code in the question). Function should prefer phrases with the lowest index over the longest.

Comment: @Stonecold Yes (and this is implemented). But you say "It should return only one item (first match), **and phrases should take precedence over single words**.", so `'it is'` should take precedence over `'reallylongword'` in `'reallylongword it is'`? (I swapped the order of the long word and the phrase consisting of two shorter words to not run into the case where the first found match is  returned.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant longest string should be preferred. For example, between 'reallylong', 'reallylongword' and 'it is' second is a match in a 'reallylongword it is'. 'it is' is never considered because it's not first matched string.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case your code is correctly implementing that, but your description could be more precise :)